# jquery slider click event gives value that is one greater than on slide

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a jquery slider and for some reason or another the slider has been returning values +-1 from the desired value.  As of right now, when I click on the timeline it gives me back one value greater than where I actually clicked.

I've been trying to correct the value when "change" is hit but "change" is hit also from dragging the square sliding thing (lack of better term) and when you click animate, which is a custom event.

Is there any other way I can check when the user just clicks on some point on the timeline?  Or has anyone had an error similar to this where the slider values are off by 1?

```
el.slider({
    min: 0,
    max: 24,
    step: 1,
    value: 17,
    create: function() {
        _this.updateSelectorValue(el, true);
    },
    change: function( event, ui ) {
        debugger;
        _this.updateSelectorValue(el);
    },
    start: function( event, ui ) {
        _this.updateSelectorValue(el);
    },
    stop: function( event, ui ) {
        _this.updateSelectorValue(el);
    },
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
        _this.showValueInHandle(el, ui);
    }
});
updateSelectorValue: function(e, i) {
    //debugger;
    var init = (typeof i === "undefined") ? false : i;
    var value = e.slider("option","value");
    e.find(".ui-slider-handle")
      .addClass("btn btn-primary")
      .text(App.CommonFunctionsController.formatTimeString(value, false));
    if (init) {
        $('.btn.btn-primary.pm-peak').click();
        $('.btn-pm-peak').addClass('focus');
    } else {
        $('.btn.btn-primary.custom').click();
        $('.btn-custom').addClass('focus');
    }
    this._context.set('currentValue', value);
},
```

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle demonstrating the problem?